# How do I force LaTeX to show tables in the section where they are made?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have the following problem:

My section 7.2 contains a lot of tables. Now it shows 2 tables, and then there is a space left on the page, that is not big enough for the next table. 
Therefore, section 7.3 starts at that empty space.
However, after that, there are still two pages full of tables that belong to section 7.2, so I prefer section 7.3 to start after these tables.

Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `!` in arguments of `table` gives LaTeX more flexibility and `\clearpage` forces putting all floats before a new page.

For example `book.cls` sets

```
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
```

and `!` overrides these  restrictions.

Comment: `!` gives LaTeX *more* flexibility?  Doesn't this option force LaTeX to put it where you specify?  +1 for `\clearpage` though - this can easily be hooked onto the beginning of `\section` to provide drop-in functionality.

Comment: @SeanAllred `!` is not `Here`. It omits limits of text part, floats part, etc., given by a style.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now - will this be in `texdoc tabular` or the like?

Comment: @SeanAllred I have just added fragments of `book.cls` and additional comment to my answer.